# How to save state of current MPMediaItem and respond to changed value when entering foreground

Tags: iphone, objective-c, background, nsuserdefaults, mpmusicplayercontroller

So I'm trying to develop a music game that uses the iPod music library. The user picks a song based on a prompt. Because I'm using `[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer]`, it's possible the user changed the song in the iPod app before coming back to the app. If that's the case, I want it to call `[musicPlayer stop]`. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to save the currently playing song and check it against the currently playing song when the app returns from background. Check the code below.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    MPMusicPlayerController *musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *persistantID = [musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID];
    [prefs setValue:persistantID forKey:@"NOWPLAYING_ID"];

}
```

And

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    MPMusicPlayerController *musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *persistantID = [prefs stringForKey:@"NOWPLAYING_ID"];
    if (persistantID == [musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID]) {
    }
    else {
        [musicPlayer stop];
    }
    [prefs setValue:nil forKey:@"NOWPLAYING_ID"];

}
```

Can anyone give me a hand? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application    {
    self.mediaItemSavedWhenAppSuspended = [musicPlayer nowPlayingItem];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    MPMediaItem *nowPlayingItem = [musicPlayer nowPlayingItem];
    NSNumber *playingItem = [nowPlayingItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID];
    NSNumber *previousItem = [self.mediaItemSavedWhenAppSuspended valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID];

    if( [playingItem compare:previousItem] == NSOrderedSame )   {   //  same track still playing
   }
```

Comment: How would I save the media item when suspended? And why can't I just save the Persistent ID of the media item instead? However, this makes a lot of sense. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, save the Persistent ID instead. Just add NSNumber *previousItem to your header file instead of MPMediaItem *mediaItemSavedWhenAppSuspended.

Comment: Good try but `if([currentSavedPersistantID compare:self.savedPersistantID] == NSOrderedSame) {
    }` is throwing an exception. You sure that the ID is a number? I thought it was an `NSString`, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Figured it out. It can be a string (maybe also a number), and I just did `if (self.savedPersistantID) {}` to only check for a value if it existed. Silly me :) Thanks for your help!